# Consecutive plots numbering

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

In R Markdown I generate a report that contain multiple plots. I need to add "Fig. ##" to the title of each plot, so that these numbers are consecutive.
At the moment my approach is to use variable `fig` and add 1 to it after each plot.

```
library(ggplot2);

fig = 1;

ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x = cyl,
                 y = disp))+
  labs(title = paste0("Fig. ", fig, ". Cyl vs Disp"));
fig = fig + 1;

## Some extra code or chunk break

ggplot(iris)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                 y = Petal.Length))+
  labs(title = paste0("Fig. ", fig, ". Sepal vs Petal"));
fig = fig + 1;
```

My problem is that I often forget to add `fig = fig + 1;` after the plot. Is there any elegant way how to avoid this repetitive typing?

UPDATE: reprex was updated to more clearly show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to do it this way

```r
library(tidyverse)
fn_plot <- function(data, x, y, fig){
  ggplot(data)+
    geom_point(aes(x = .data[[x]],
                   y = .data[[y]])) +
    labs(title = paste0("Fig. ", fig, " . ", x, " vs ", y))
}

data <- list(mtcars, iris)
x <- c("cyl", "Sepal.Length")
y <- c("disp", "Petal.Length")
fig <- 1:2

l <- list(data, x, y, fig)

pmap(.l = l, .f = fn_plot)
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, my reprex was not very clear in what I want. I've updated the reprex to show the problem in a better way - I can't programmatically generate plots as they are quite different from each other.